# Missing Component Pieces from a PCB

Tags: reverse-engineering

This PCB is from a old Sharp 1999 TV I have been reverse engineering lately; also sorry for any bad images.  I have noticed that there are some "missing" components in the holes of: **D4002, D4003, D4001, D4004, and C4002**.  Are there certain components that were once in those holes as part of the design?

[image: Missing Stuff]

Comment: Same answer as your other question.

Comment: @brhans So I could add a diode, zener diode, and capacitor to the  PCB and it would still work?

Comment: Unless you have the circuit diagram of the PCB, there's no easy way to know what will happen if you start adding random parts to it.

Comment: General answer to this question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/138378/why-does-there-seem-to-be-a-missing-component-in-many-pcbs

Comment: @DarnessSigma - there is really no point in proposing edits to fundamentally bad questions.  Slight wording or formatting changes will not turn them into good ones.  Also, you generally should not propose edits which change what is being asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They could be parts that are used for a different TV or some other product, they could be parts that were in the original design, but later deemed unnecessary.  It could also be a cost saving measure (two parts in parallel in case two lower value parts were cheaper than a higher value part).

The board *might* work if you add those components back in, or it might stop working if those components are put in.  It is difficult to tell without reverse engineering the whole thing.